# Puppet Zendesk configuration

Tags: puppet, rhel, zendesk

Hello I trying to configure zendesk ticketing for my puppet on single RHEL EC2.

I followed below link:

```
https://forge.puppetlabs.com/jamtur01/zendesk
```

I was able to setup everything as said in above link.

Did any one had success with this?

I particularity did not understand line

```
Run the Puppet client and sync the report as a plugin
```

Please help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Run the Puppet client and sync the report as a plugin

This is just saying run your puppet client and tickets will be created when your puppet agent fails a run.  Did you tested it with fail run ? It should create a Zendesk ticket.